# How to slice a four-dimensional array using two two-dimensional masks in a single operation?

Tags: python, numpy

Lets say I have an `shape=(70,50,40,30)` array with fancy strides,

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.rand(70,50,40,30)
X.strides = X.strides[:3] + (0,)
```

Note that the `0`-stride is just an example to explain the problem.

and the two two-dimensional binary masks

```py
mask1 = (np.random.rand(*X.shape[:2]) < 0.1)
mask2 = (np.random.rand(*X.shape[2:]) < 0.1)
```

with `mask1.sum() == 348` and `mask2.sum() == 114` positive entries.

Then, `X[mask1][:,mask2]` yields a matrix of shape `(348, 114)`.

This is the expected result. The downside is, that the expression `X[mask1]` yields a copy of the data in `X`, even though a large amount of the copied data is then thrown away by the second slicing operation `[:,mask2]`. This is not a problem for small matrices, however, for very large matrices, where `mask2` only has very few positive entries, this is inefficient. Also, for large `X`, reshaping `X` is not an option, since due to the fancy strides, this will create a copy.

How can the slicing `X[mask1][:,mask2]` be performed in a single operation?

Comment: Reshaping to (3500,1200) may reduce conceptual complexity.  `np.nonzero` will produce indexing arrays, that may be easier to apply.

Comment: The problem is that `X` in my case is a fancy-indexed array, so reshaping it already produces a huge copy, I want to avoid. I will edit my question and add this information. Reshaping `X` is not an option. @hpaulj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: np.random.seed(0) 
   ...: X = np.random.rand(70,50,40,30) 
   ...: X.strides = X.strides[:3] + (0,)                                                             
In [2]: mask1 = (np.random.rand(*X.shape[:2]) < 0.1) 
   ...: mask2 = (np.random.rand(*X.shape[2:]) < 0.1)                                                 
In [3]: mask1.sum()                                                                                  
Out[3]: 348
In [4]: mask2.sum()                                                                                  
Out[4]: 114
In [5]: Y=X[mask1][:,mask2]                                                                          
In [6]: Y.shape                                                                                      
Out[6]: (348, 114)
```

lets try array indexing:

```
In [7]: idx1 = np.nonzero(mask1)                                                                     
In [8]: idx2 = np.nonzero(mask2)                                                                     
In [11]: Z = X[idx1[0][:,None],idx1[1][:,None],idx2[0],idx2[1]]                                      
In [12]: Z.shape                                                                                     
Out[12]: (348, 114)
In [13]: np.allclose(Y,Z)                                                                            
Out[13]: True
```

And compare the times:

```
In [14]: timeit Y=X[mask1][:,mask2]                                                                  
695 µs ± 7.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [15]: %%timeit 
    ...: I,J = np.nonzero(mask1) 
    ...: K,L = np.nonzero(mask2) 
    ...: Z = X[I[:,None],J[:,None],K,L] 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                             
433 µs ± 1.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

A modest improvement.

Comment: Now that I see the solution, it absolutely makes sense. Thanks!